# devise rails current_user vs user_signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise on Rails 4.1
My question is regarding the helpers and how they relate to sessions.
current_user : tells you if there is a user session available for the user.
user_signed_in: tells you if the user is authenticated.

I cannot understand how a there can be a current_user if the user_signed_in? is false?

What is the difference between the two methods, and how does it relate to sessions.

THanks.
Richard Madson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*current_user* method returns current signed-in user, while *user_signed_in?* method is used to verify if any user is signed in and returns true or false. if *user_signed_in?* is false then *current_user* method will return nil.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Answer (score 10):

`user_signed_in?` is provided as a convenience. You are correct in your assertion that if `user_signed_in?` is `false`, there will never be a `current_user`.

In the [devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e33d285e4ae2130fe9acd00ef60782ae8bee6ad9/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L119), we can see:

```
def #{mapping}_signed_in?
  !!current_#{mapping}
end
```

(where `user` takes the place of `#{mapping}`)

`user_signed_in?` simply returns the truthiness of `current_user`, ie, `false` if `current_user` is `nil`.