# Rails test - checking if user is signed in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, warden

I am trying to test that someone is able to login to my site by making a POST request to my `SessionsController`. I've seen this way recommended in a few places:

```
it 'must be able to sign in a user' do
  user = create(:user)
  post :create, format: :js, user: {email: user.email, password: user.password, remember_me: 0}
  assert_response :success
  @controller.current_user.must_equal user
end
```

But this test is not correct. Calling `@controller.current_user` will attempt to authenticate the user using the posted parameters and will return `user` if the supplied email/password is correct. There is no guarantee that the `create` action is actually calling `sign_in` or `current_user`.

Even if I re-write the test to check that these methods are called, it's possible that other methods could be called e.g. `sign_out`.

Is there a more definitive way to ultimately check if a user is logged in, and if so, who the user is?

EDIT -

For example, the following test will pass

```
it 'must sign in a user' do
   @controller.current_user.must_equal nil
   post :create, format: :js, user: {email: @user.email, password: @user.password, remember_me: 0}
   assert_response :success
   @controller.current_user.must_equal @user
end
```

when the SessionsController#create action is:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render nothing: true, status: 200
      }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793597/how-to-access-devise-current-user-in-a-rspec-feature-test

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think that helps. I'm not having trouble calling current_user.

Comment: is `.current_user` a method that attempts to log the user in, or is it an attr_reader for an instance variable? If the former, then it seems what you're describing is the expected behavior.

Comment: `current_user` is a method that will attempt to log the user in. If you run the test I outlined in the question with a completely empty controller action, the test will still pass

Comment: How you are handling sessions in controller? are you using rails `session`?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution with minimal changes to proposed code in the question:**

You need to initialize the system before the test starts. Try prepending following code before your i`t 'must be able to sign in a user' do` code:

```
before (:each) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_out user
end
```

This should turn your test into a valid test for your post controller.

**Explanation:**

My assumption is, that your test above always succeeds, because the user is already signed in (by other tests run before this one). You could verify this by using `byebug` in the line after `it` and run `current_user` in `bybug's` console. If it is not `nil`, the user is already signed in, which is invalidating your test.

Note, that (different from what is discussed above in the comments), `current_user` does not change the status of the user; it is a read-only function.

**Shorter/cleaner solution:**

In my opinion, there is a a cleaner way to perform such a test like follows:

```
def sign_in_via_post(user)
  post :create, format: :js, user: {email: user.email, password: user.password, remember_me: 0}
end

...

before (:each) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  sign_out user
end

it 'must be able to sign in a user' do
   { sign_in_via_post user }.should change { current_user }.from(nil).to(user)
end
```

With the `should change from nil to user` statement, you verify, that the user was logged out before the test begins and that the user is logged in, after the test has been performed.

Note, that the part

```
   { sign_in_via_post user }.should change { current_user }.from(nil).to(user)
```

is equivalent to the (maybe easier to understand) code

```
   { sign_in_via_post user }.should change { user_signed_in? }.from(false).to(true)
```

as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042117/devise-rails-current-user-vs-user-signed-in).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do believe that `current_user` can update the state of the user. I've added a sample test in my original question that I believe illustrates the issue.

Comment: I just had a thought, maybe there is a before_action/filter that is doing something, but I can't check right now. Perhaps you are right

Comment: @user1063998: have you had a chance to test my suggestion? I have invested quite a bit of time to come up with the solution (at least I think, it is the solution). In any case, it was a good exercise, but I would prefer it to have it checked by the person who has asked.